# Workflow deployment with enabling Log Analytics in Azure Logic App using Rest API

Tags: azure, workflow, azure-logic-apps, azure-log-analytics

I am trying to deploy workflows in Azure using workflows Rest API's(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/logic/workflows ). I want to enable Log Analytics Workspace while deploying this workflow in Logic App. This is straight forward in portal while creating logic app. But I didn't find any document or information to pass log analytics workspace while creating workflow definition(JSON File). Please let me know, if there is a way to pass it

Comment: It s possible using ARM template if you're interested in

Comment: If it's possible in ARM Template, then I am fine with it and I will use ARM Template deployment API's to deploy it. Please let me know, some sample template to achieve it. Thanks in advance..

Answer (score -1):

In a comment above you mentioned "*If it's possible in ARM Template, then I am fine with it and I will use ARM Template deployment API's to deploy it.*"

Here's an example, feel free to amend it so that it suits your needs:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "logicapp-name": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": "testLogicApp",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "Name of the Logic App"
            }
        },
        "loganalytics-workspace-resourceid": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": "/subscriptions/11111111-2222-3333-4444-555555555555/resourcegroups/testResourceGroup/providers/microsoft.operationalinsights/workspaces/testLogAnalyticsWorkspace",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "Resource ID of the Log Analytics workspace"
            }
        }
    },
    "variables": {
        "logAnalyticsSettingName": "testDiagnosticSettingName"
    },
    "resources": [
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Logic/workflows/providers/diagnosticSettings",
            "name": "[concat(parameters('logicapp-name'),'/Microsoft.Insights/', variables('logAnalyticsSettingName'))]",
            "apiVersion": "2017-05-01-preview",
            "properties": {
                "workspaceId": "[parameters('loganalytics-workspace-resourceid')]",
                "logs": [
                    {
                        "category": "WorkflowRuntime",
                        "enabled": true,
                        "retentionPolicy": {
                            "days": 0,
                            "enabled": false
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "metrics": [
                    {
                        "timeGrain": "PT1M",
                        "enabled": true,
                        "retentionPolicy": {
                            "enabled": false,
                            "days": 0
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: with logic app standard we deploy logic app workflow seperatly, the answer you shown will enable the workflow at the time of creation of logic app.

Comment: @RakeshSuryawanshi The question wasn't about Standard Logic Apps (and the appropriate tag wasn't used) - the answer perfectly works for Consumption Logic Apps.